# Mirror reflection and orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, orthogonality, reflection

I know a orthogonal transformation can be represented by the product of a series of mirror reflections.

But I meet a question which requires one to show that the number of the mirror reflections in the product can be no greater than $n$, the dimension of the linear space, where $n\ge2$.

I want to use mathematical induction to solve this question, but I got stuck on processing the situation with $n=2$, that is, a orthogonal transformation on a linear space with dimension $2$ can be represented by the product of one or two mirror reflection.

Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: with scalars in $\mathbb R$, all vectors mentioned here will have 2 norm of one (1.) prove that for any , there is a Householder matrix =−2 (orthogonal and symmetric) such that =; (2.) in a manner similar to the proof of Schur's triangularization theorem, use (1) systematically against orthogonal matrix , starting with its first column, i.e. select $^{(1)}$ with $\mathbf x:=\mathbf q_1$and $\mathbf y := \mathbf e_1$.... after (at most)  $n$ reflections you will have  reduced Q to the identity matrix, i.e.  $P^{(n)}...P^{(1)}Q = I_n$